# How to mutate Swift Dictionary of Dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary, nsdictionary

I have a Swift Dictionary that contains Dictionary, and I wanted to use stored property to access a key-value:

```
  var json = [NSObject:AnyObject]()
  var title: String {
    get {
      return (self.json["category"]! as [NSObject: AnyObject])["title"] as String
    }
    set {
//      var dict = (self.json["category"]! as [NSObject: AnyObject])
//      dict["title"] = newValue

      (self.json["category"]! as [NSObject: AnyObject])["title"] = newValue
    }
  }
```

The last line throws an compilation error: Operand of postfix '!' should have optional type; type is '(NSObject, AnyObject)'

Apparently based on the compilation error, the compiler think self.json["category"] is type of (NSObject, AnyObject) that cannot be be converted to Dictionary!

I thought this should be a common usage? How would you do normally to access Dictionary of Dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

I confess that I still don't understand the mechanisms at work here, but I do see the pattern: Swift doesn't like to downcast from `AnyObject` to mutable types of objects. It's more forgiving downcasting to immutable types, which is why you notice the asymmetry above: your getter is okay but your setter is not.

I don't know what all of your constraints are, but the seemingly more reliable way to do what you're attempting is to use `NSMutableDictionary`, which allows downcasting to your heart's content:

```
class UsingNSMutableDictionary {
    var json = NSMutableDictionary()
    var title: String {
        get {
            return self.json["category"]!["title"] as String
        }
        set {
            (self.json["category"] as NSMutableDictionary)["title"] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Dealing with JSON in Swift has spawned a lot of discussion and more than a few libraries. If you're looking for practical working solutions to getting something working with JSON, I suggest you try one of those libraries -- they tend to take a more robust approach to dealing in Swift with the dynamic types inherent in processing JSON.

Comment: native swift dictionary is value type, while nsdictionary is reference type. that is how I choose which one to use. Having say that, I do agree with you I seem to have more trouble in native swift collection types. btw, I think your UsingSwiftNative setter doesn't work, either.

Comment: You're right! Sorry about that. I'll yank it as it seems superfluous regardless.

Answer (score 0):

That is a tuple. What we need is a dictionary.

```
set {
            //      var dict = (self.json["category"]! as [NSObject: AnyObject])
            //      dict["title"] = newValue
            //      self.json["category"] = dict
            var category: [NSObject: AnyObject] = self.json["category"] as [NSObject: AnyObject]
            category["title"] = newValue
    }
```

Comment: Yes, the compiler does tell me that is a tuple, I just don't understand why I cannot combine these two lines into one line.